# Can ziv lempel efficiency be improved by compressing longer repetitions

Tags: algorithm, compression, lempel-ziv-76

I have a question - I was introduced to a version of Ziv- Lempel that encodes only repetitions of size 3 or longer(repetitions of 1 or 2 characters aren't encoded - the characters themselves are placed to the coded string and not the (m,k) value). I was asked if it is possible to improve ziv Lempel encoding efficiency (in terms of the length of the coded string - not time complexity).

I think that In terms of length of the coded string - there can be a scenario when not encoding a 3 length repetition at location p and instead encoding a repetition that starts at location p+1 or p+2 may yield better results - this also appears in the theory that I read: I have added a photo of the relevant paragraph that speaks about just that (but no examples are given). Every example I managed to find so far is one that either a code that encodes repetitions of length 3 can also detect.

Here is the paragraph that speaks of the fact that such a text exists:

> Our compression algorithm as described so far is *greedy*: Any repeat of length 3 or more is reported and employed right away. Sometimes this is not optimal: We could have an [*m*<sub>1</sub>, *k*<sub>1</sub>] repeat in position *p*, and an [*m*<sub>2</sub>, *k*<sub>2</sub>] repeat in position *p*+1 or *p*+2, with *k*<sub>1</sub> << *k*<sub>2</sub>. Thus a non-greedy algorithm may result in improved compression.

[(original image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MYgf.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  gzip's and zlib's deflate algorithm uses "lazy" matching, which defers the decision to emit a match until the next character in order to see if there is a longer match there.  That is definitely a win.

Answer (score 1):

This is technically called LZ non-greedy parsing approach.
As Mark mentioned, gzip uses [that](http://www.gzip.org/algorithm.txt), but for only p+1 skip.

In [this document](http://www.cs.uvic.ca/~nigelh/Publications/LZ-non-greedy.pdf), you'll find more universal encoder with multiple details of that feature of LZ algorithm